# Concatenate the date in each element

Tags: javascript, html, date

I want to concatenate the dates. This is my codes, I created first the year today and next date that I add 1 month to become 2019. I don't know what the problem is why it didn't display the result.

```js
function myFunction() {

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    var date = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
    
    var d1 = new Date();
    var n1 = d1.getFullYear()+1;
    var date1 = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = n1;
    
    var str3 = "-";
    var res = date.concat(str3,date1);
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = res;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p>Click the button to display the full year of todays date.</p>


<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="disp"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know what the problem is why it didn't display the result.

Because you are getting

> "Uncaught TypeError: date.concat is not a function",

`date` is a **number**, it doesn't have concat method. Convert it to `String` first.

```
var res = String(date).concat(str3,date1);
```

**Demo**

```js
function myFunction() {

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    var date = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
    
    var d1 = new Date();
    var n1 = d1.getFullYear()+1;
    var date1 = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = n1;
    console.log(date, date1);
    var str3 = "-";
    var res = String(date).concat(str3,date1);
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = res;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p>Click the button to display the full year of todays date.</p>


<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="disp"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Iv'e got it now.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Far simpler to just do `date + str3 + date1` or `date + '-' + date1`.

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a number. `Number` does not have `concat` function. Convert it into a string.

```js
function myFunction() {

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    var date = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n+""; // convert to string
    
    var d1 = new Date();
    var n1 = d1.getFullYear()+1;
    var date1 = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = n1+"";
    
    var str3 = "-";
    var res = date.concat(str3,date1);
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = res;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p>Click the button to display the full year of todays date.</p>


<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="disp"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)

> It is strongly recommended to use the string concatenation operators
>   (+, +=) instead of this method for perfomance reasons

```
 var res = date + str3 + date1;
```